# An Question related to calculating $H^4(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

This is an assignment question with $3$ steps as follows:

> $1.$ Prove that $H^2(K(\mathbb{Z},2);\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2.$ Use this generator to obtain a map $K(\mathbb{Z},2)\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)$. Prove that the homotopy fibre of the map is $\simeq$ $K(\mathbb{Z}/2)$.
>
> $2.$ In the above fibration $\big(K(\mathbb{Z},2)\xrightarrow{f}{} K(\mathbb{Z},2)\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)\big),$ prove that we get an induced map $q:Cone (f)\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2).$ Prove that $q_*$ is surjective on homotopy groups.
>
> $3.$ Prove that $q$ is an $4$-equivalence. Use this to deduce that $H^4(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2))\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$.

I have solved the first two parts of the question but I am completely clueless about the last part. I don't know how to calculate the homotopy groups of $Cone(f)$, I guess there must be a way around it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can compute $H^2(Cone(f), \mathbb Z/2)$  and the induced maps $H^2(Cone(f), \mathbb Z/2)\to H^2(S^k, \mathbb Z/2)$ for $k$ low enough and maps $S^k \to Cone(f)$ ? For $k\neq 2$, it should yield something interesting; and for $k=2$, you might actually have to compute $\pi_2(Cone(f))$ but I think this should be reasonable

Comment: @Max, so following your suggestion for $k\neq 2$ say we have $S^k\xrightarrow{g} C_f\xrightarrow{q} K(\mathbb{Z}/2,2)$. The composition is null homotopic. From this how do we say $g\simeq *$?

Comment: No actually I think I spoke too quickly, I don't see how to get anywhere from my hint.

Comment: I think I might have a solution, but it uses the Serre spectral sequence : are you familiar with it ?

Comment: No, I haven't learnt it yet. My prof actually gave us the solution. I will post it here soon. Thanks anyway.